# matlab symbolic equality wrong

Tags: matlab, symbols

Why does matlab return a zero instead of a 1 for this command

```
isequal(3*sin(x1)*M+3*sin(x1)*m,3*sin(x1)*(M+m))
```

similarly it returns a zero if I do

```
isequal(3*sin(x1)*M+3*sin(x1)*m,simplify(3*sin(x1)*M+3*sin(x1)*m))
```

When in both cases it should return 1 (true)??

Comment: [Create Symbolic Numbers, Variables, and Expressions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html)